# Why do willows go to the Cathedral?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, pavlo-tychyna, pavlo-tychyna-poetry-collection

*Cathedral* by Pavlo Tychyna starts as follows:

> Willows to one side,
> Beggars to the other.
> the willows bend and bend and bend.
> The beggars stoop over.

Why is the Cathedral attended by those two groups in particular?

Comment: original text: https://ukrclassic.com.ua/katalog/t/tichina-pavlo/886-pavlo-tichina-u-sobor

Comment: Why are you interpreting trees as a ‘group attending the cathedral’ rather than plants growing outside it?